# How to get files belonging to the current logged in user? Relations

Tags: django

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="files")

class UserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
```

**views.py**

```
def my_files(request):
    user = request.user
    myfile = UserFile.objects.filter(user=user)

    return render_to_response('myfiles.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How to get files belonging to the current logged in user?

Comment: What is wrong with this lines `def my_files(request):
    user = request.user
    myfile = UserFile.objects.filter(user=user)` ??

Comment: @Silwestpl how to display my file in template? I'm trying: `{% for f in myfile %} {{f.files.name}} {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files = File.objects.filter(userfile__user=request.user)
```

and template is just:

```
{% for file in files %}{{ file.src }}{% endfor %}
```

see [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)